# What is "SEPA-Direct Debit Bulk Core"?

Tags: money-transfer, online-banking, germany, direct-debit

I just noticed that on my German bank account, I received around 15€. Under the transaction description, it only says `SEPA-Direct Debit Bulk Core`.

Normally, the transaction descriptions for interest or for money coming from other accounts are a bit more useful. I myself am not from EU, so I'm not really sure what this means and Google isn't giving me any useful results.

Comment: Did you ask the bank? What did they say?

Comment: @Michael Kjörling Not yet, because the bank is trying to make itself difficult to ask questions to.

Comment: Did you make a direct debit, i.e., collecting money from someone’s bank account?

Comment: @unor No, I did not.

Comment: Google spit this out as top result:  http://www.europeanpaymentscouncil.eu/index.cfm/sepa-direct-debit/sepa-direct-debit-core-scheme-sdd-core/  What it tells me is that it is a legit transfer of money to you from someone else.

Comment: @Xalorous  Thanks for the link! I couldn't find it on Google at all, back when I was looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it took some effort to get an explanation from my bank.

Turns out that some supermarkets use direct debit as a method of transferring money for purchases payed by so-called "EC" cards here. I was told that for some reason, a supermarket decided to reverse one of such transactions.